# Is there a way to record the audio directly from the soundcard (e.g. using ffmpeg)?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, recording

I know there it is possible to record sound from the speaker of the computer using command such as:

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i ":0" -t 10 audiocapture.aiff
```

But as the recorded sound is far from perfect (due to the imperfection of the microphone), is there a way to record the audio directly from the soundcard (e.g. using ffmpeg)?

Comment: This post is useful: https://superuser.com/questions/597227/linux-arecord-capture-sound-card-output-rather-than-microphone-input

Answer (score 1):

open  pavucontrol ,
go to input devices and mute the mic

open termial ,

enable loopback

```
pactl load-module module-loopback
```

start a test recording

```
arecord -f cd > out.wav
```

go back to pavucontrol recording tab and switch ALSA capture to monitor mode

stop recording `Ctrl+c`

now you can record from the sound card as you liked

```
arecord -f cd > out.wav
```

and check out arecord manuall for more options

Comment: Many thanks for your comment @Yunus. I am running a MacOS. Do you know by any means the corresponding command for a mac?

Comment: i thought for linux , i don't use mac but i googled a bit they say you enable loopback from system preferences >> sound which cause sound to disappeare from speakers(normal), and then use ffmpeg to list devices you may see the loopback as address ":x" to use for record

Comment: Many thanks for your update @yunus, I did what you say (switch sound of HDMI and tried ":1" and ":x2" but still could not make it work. I upvoted your answer though

Comment: just tested a working workaround: install "loopback audio" app , and then switch sound output to "loopback" , so your ffmpeg cmd wil work perfectly.  https://rogueamoeba.com/loopback/